# How to access PostgreSQL database with python 3.5

Tags: windows, postgresql, psycopg2, python-3.5

I am using python 3.5 and I want to connect to a PostgreSQL database. What is the best driver to use? I would prefer psycopg2 but it only supports python 3.4 (at least officially).

Would psycopg2 work with python3.5? Where can I get Windows binaries to try it out?

Answer (score 0):

**Download**:   psycopg2-2.6.2.win32-py3.5-pg9.5.3-release.exe from [HERE](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/), then run the following in a Windows command prompt:

`C:\path\to\project> easy_install /path/to/ psycopg2-2.6.2.win32-py3.5-pg9.5.3-release.exe`

Use [this wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_psycopg2_with_PostgreSQL) as a guide to using psycopg2.